# Facebook API for Share returning empty results set

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook API. I am building a Facebook app to fetch all the name of people who shared, commented and liked a post in a tabular format. I am able to get the like and comment details through Facebook API but can not find and proper API to get the share details.

I am using

https://graph.facebook.com/post_id?fields=sharedposts&access_token=my_access_token.

This API is returning an empty result set. And I have granted all the available permission to the access_tokn. Can anyone tell me ,Is there any other API that I can use. I saw a option of scraping the Facebook page for share,but I don't want to go that way because Facebook keeps on updating every thing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem as you, but I think I'm going a little step forward.
Try adding a limit to your sharedposts and maybe it will return some data:
Try this way:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/sharedposts?access_token=my_access_token&limit=1000
```

That should work for a regular post.

EDIT: Maybe the problem could be that althought you have granted all the perms to the token, the people who share that posts have to accept that permission too.
Otherway your JSON won't return any data.

Answer (score 2):

The `/sharedposts` endpoint will -only- retrieve posts from users who have -also- granted your app. This means that even though a post might be public on a users' timeline, unless they have also granted your app permissions, you will not be able to retrieve that post.

For example: a user posted to a page and the post is public. This post can be retrieved with an access token. Let's assume that the user also shared this post to their own timeline. But, since the user has not granted permissions to your app, you will not be able to see this post using the `/sharedposts` edge on the original post (on the page). This also holds if the user shared their post publicly to his timeline.

This behaviour is by design; the API is more restrictive in returning user data than the website is. This holds for multiple endpoint and this is one of the examples where it is the case.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1404733043148335