# Facebook API Photo's SharedPosts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I'm trying to get the */sharedposts* edge of a photo.

This link works in the browser: 
https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=10152429679154254

And when I query the API for *10152429679154254*, I get the info about it along with likes and comments, but there are no shares.

The API reference suggests that *objectid/sharedposts* should work, but when I do that I get an empty set...

Any ideas?

Comment: We are to trying to figure out a solution over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173937/facebook-api-for-share-returning-empty-results-set/28462726#28462726

Answer (score 1):

Looks like facebook has a bug report for this and is working through all the comments. Might find some helpful info here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1404733043148335/