# Facebook sharedposts issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook id : 821829404554599.
I want to get all sharedposts, but  
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=821829404554599%3Ffields%3Dsharedposts&version=v2.2&

returns only 4.
As we can see there https://www.facebook.com/sabidom.ru/photos/a.437568379647372.101024.431119086958968/821829404554599/
more then 40 sharedposts. Whats the reason?

Comment: also there are no info about my sharedpost in me/feed or me/posts, but the post is real, still on my page

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible hypothesis due your data:
1 - Facebook has a problem with sharedposts: `https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1404733043148335/`

2 - The more possible option is that Facebook only will give you the data of the users that allow give you that data. For example, users must share that posts as public, for Facebook can read and give it to you. Furthermore users have to give read_stream perms to your APP (*and make a Token for asking with that APP_ID*).

We are trying to figure out a solution over here:
[Facebook API for Share returning empty results set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173937/facebook-api-for-share-returning-empty-results-set/28462726#28462726)