# How to get users who shared my post using Opengraph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

can i use opengraph to recieve name and id who shared my post? I tried

```
1068957016482203/sharedposts
```

but was empty data, what i'm doing wrong?

p.s. sorry for the frequent question, but other answers was for <2.0 api version and don't work today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Graph API doesn't let you get **who** shared a post. You can get the number of shares:

```
1068957016482203/?fields=shares
```

And you can get the number of likes and the number of comments as well as who liked and who commented on your post. It's just **who** shared that's not available.

Comment: are you sure? but what makes the «sharedposts»?

Comment: "This edge represents any posts where the original object was shared on Facebook." so theoretically it should lead you to all shares but in practice there seem to be problems with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479613/facebook-sharedposts-issue. Most often you get 0 results.

Comment: Thank you, krychu.  **ckin facebook(